# Entity Framework insert into table with identity from another table

Tags: entity-framework, identity

I would like to ask about inserting new record into table through entity framework. I have composited primary key (id and department_id). Department_Id is constant because there are departments and each department can create new record. Each record is replicated to all departments. Id is identity by department. But it cannot be identity on column because when all departments can create record with Id=1 but department_id will be different. 
Now I solve it that I create new record in dummy table which has identity column and I get this value into Id column and save record. So for each table I have specialized table with identity column to generated Id value.

Table Customer (Id int, Department_Id int, …) Id, Department_Id is primary key.

Table CustomerIdentity(Id int identity(1,1), Dummy int null).

I have stored procedure to save new record:

```
declare @id int 

declare @department_id int = 10 -- constant for department 10 

insert into CustomerIdentity(Dummy) values (null) 

set @id = scope_identity() 

insert into Customer(Id, Department_Id, …) values (@id, @department_id, …)
```

I refactor this code to extract logic from stored procedure to C# where I have Customer entity. Id cannot be identity because there could be records as:

Id   | Department_Id

1    | 1              -- record from department 1.

1    | 2              -- record from department 2.

1    | N              -- record from department N.

So there is Identity table which holds identity value for each department. Each record from department 1..N is replicated to all departments. 
How to set EF to give value for Id column from another table?

Comment: Please show your code. A description will never be clear enough.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why Cutomer.Id is not an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

To do something with EF I would look at something like:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var customerIdentity = new CustomerIdentity();
    context.CustomerIdentities.Add(customerIdentity);
    context.SaveChanges();
    var newCustomer = new Customer
    {
        DepartmentId = _DepartmentId, // I.e. "10"
        CustomerId = customerIdentity.CustomerId
        // ...
    }
    // Optionally you could delete the CustomerIdentity record.
    context.CustomerIdentities.Remove(customerIdentity);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This assumes that each department will have its own database which would manage its own identity tables for the ids, but would be synchronized with other databases or a central database where data cross departments would be queried. The CustomerIdentity provides the sequence (autoincrement) for the IDs, so once that is retrieved (first SaveChanges call) and earmarked into the Customer record, the CustomerIdentity record can be deleted. The table would remain empty but the Identity would continue to increment. If you decide to keep the CustomerIdentity row you would want to avoid associating the Customer and CustomerIdentity entities in a relationship in EF even though for a department they would form a 1 to 1 relationship. Other departments identity counters could be higher and such a relationship would result in errors if the target database had identity up to say 50, and a record wants to get added with an ID of 65. Identity 65 doesn't yet exist so EF would throw a FK violation if you try to bring that customer record in.

Comment: Problem of this solution is when there is more complex logic. I would like to apply domain model design and CustomerIdentity object is not valid for business model. It is valid for database model. In more complex structures I can change some objects and some object can be added. It is problem because DbContext is injected into domain services and it can add some objects and some objects can be changed so I don't know which object is which when I call SaveChanges. It should be better to solve it in DbContext implementation (override SaveChanges maybe) through something like Key object.

Comment: When it comes to distributed systems where records may be replicated and synchronized between systems, the simpler option is to use unique identifiers such as UUIDs (sequential) or Snowflake rather than composite keys. Composite keys work well enough if department DBs only see their own data and you have a central DB for reporting/management that needs to see data across departments.  In that case the dept DB can auto-increment the ID and use a constant Dept. ID while the central DB is set up without the auto-increment.